# How to retrieve value of hidden field in twig?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

How to retrieve value of hidden field in twig?

PFB screenshot:
[image: How to retrieve value of hidden field in twi]

I am able to retrieve value of "Partition Count" field when not disabled. But not able to retrieve it's value when disabled.

Exact requirement:
1) If "Partition Count" field is **Disabled** from Drupal Admin, then field **should not be displayed**. **But this value needs to be retrieved in twig file** as display of "Reference Paragraph" will vary according to the value of "Partition Count".

2) If "Partition Count" field is **Enabled** from Drupal Admin, then field should be **displayed**. In this case, I am able to retrieve "Partition Count" field value in twig file.

---

paragraph.html.twig:: https://github.com/WondrousLLC/paragraphs_starter_pack/blob/master/template/paragraph/paragraph.html.twig

Comment: You can get all fields from the entity object. If this is a node: `{{ node.field_partition_count.value }}`

Comment: Where exactly did you disable it at? `Manage Form Display` or `Manage Display` ?

Comment: If you have nested paragraphs and this is a paragraph referencing paragraphs: `{{ paragraph.field_partition_count.value }}`

Comment: @4k4, your code will work only if "partition count" field is not disabled.

Comment: @No Sssweat, from "Manage Display".

Comment: @Ayush, I'm confident you can find the field value in the entity object, but without knowing which template you have and what code is in there I can't provide an answer.

Comment: @4k4, let me give you more clarity. This is a nested paragraph and article content type is referencing this nested paragraph. I am trying to get "partition count" field value in "paragraph.html.twig".

Comment: https://github.com/WondrousLLC/paragraphs_starter_pack/blob/master/template/paragraph/paragraph.html.twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in a paragraph template contain the fully loaded paragraph entity:

*paragraph.html.twig*

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a paragraph.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - paragraph: Full paragraph entity.
```

from which you can retrieve raw values of any field, not matter whether base field or configured field or displayed or not:

```
{% set value = paragraph.field_example.value %}
```

On the contrary `{{ content }}`

```
 * - content: All paragraph items. Use {{ content }} to print them all,
 *   or print a subset such as {{ content.field_example }}. Use
 *   {{ content|without('field_example') }} to temporarily suppress the printing
 *   of a given child element.
```

contains only the fields configured to be displayed in "Manage Display".

Comment: it's working.Thanks.  But just wanted to know why do we need to append ".value" after field name? Also, How can I print complete "paragraph" entity?

Comment: See this [blog post](https://www.md-systems.ch/de/blog/techblog/2017/02/20/twig-and-entity-field-api-or-how-to-take-control-of-nodehtmltwig) from @Berdir, which is for `content` vs. `node`, but is the same for all entity templates. In this case for `content` vs. `paragraph`.