# How to print the relative url or node id for each referenced node in twig?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I am using paragraphs to render a number of nodes on a page. The nodes are obtained through an entity reference field called 'field_nodeslist' in my cards paragraph type. The cards are then rendered using a custom view layout.

Here is a snippet of my view layout:

```
<a href="????">
   <h3>{{ content.top_region|striptags}}</h3>
   <p>{{ content.middle_region }}</p>
</a>
```

The problem I am having is printing the relative path for each referenced node. I have tried the following twig commands but have not had any success so far:

```
<a href="{{ url }}">
<a href="{{ uri }}">
<a href="{{ node.id }}">
<a href="{{ link }}">
<a href"{{ content.field.0['#url'] }}">
```

The following allows me to manually specify the node id in twig however that's not what I am looking for:

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': 6 }) }}">
```

Any ideas?

**Notes/Thoughts:** In my first code snippet, the fields in 'top_region' just contains the nodes title. There was an option to link the field to content however I had to add the '*|striptag*' filter in twig due to additional markup messing up the style. Is it possible to grab the url path from the node title?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to work more in UI to configure what is in `{{ content }}` and then render the fields as they are.

If still necessary you can use `{{ node }}` respectively `{{ paragraph }}` to access all field values, see [How to retrieve value of hidden field in twig?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278437/how-to-retrieve-value-of-hidden-field-in-twig), but you can't access the url directly. You have to build this with the help of the raw database value `target id`, see [How to print the URL path of a referenced node using paragraphs?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281426/how-to-print-the-url-path-of-a-referenced-node-using-paragraphs).

BTW the result is the same as the entity method toUrl() would provide, only that this method is blocked by the twig sandbox policies. As a third (least favourable) option you can change this, too, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091324/allow-new-methods-in-sandbox-policy-in-twig-drupal-8

Comment: Thanks 4k4. Do you know how I can obtain the raw database value of target id?

Comment: `node.field_example.target_id` or `paragraph.field_example.target_id`, see your last question I've linked.

Comment: Thanks 4k4. I'm still having difficulty following despite reading over the material. Is target_id suppose to be the value of a particular node/paragraph id or am I off track?

Comment: `target_id` is the nid of the referenced node you are trying to print the relative url for.

Comment: Thanks 4k4. I thought that was the case. Is there a twig function where drupal automatically fetches the url for each node rendered that I can insert in my view layout twig template? I would  prefer not to hard code the relative path in my twig template for every node if possible.

Comment: Drupal automatically fetches the URL when configured in the display modes of the content/paragraph types.

Comment: Thanks 4K4. My end goal is to create cards that are clickable. I can configure the individuals fields through the UI to make them link to their respected content. However, I'm stuck finding a way to make the entire area of a card clickable without hard coding the path in the twig template...

Comment: OK, this is great when you have the content you want on the screen. To theme the output enable Twig Debug and locate the correct template name which outputs the HMTL markup you want to change, although to make the whole area clickable there should be a CSS solution using the existing markup.